# Mongoskin 1.4.4: Setting batchSize in an aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

One of the changes in the latest MongoDB release (2.6) results in the [cursor being returned by an aggregation query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate). This is very useful, as it allows more efficient processing of very large query result sets. I have troubles utilising this in my node app though.

**How do I retrieve the batch of results using mongoskin?**

I've tried:

```
var db = require('mongoskin').db('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var collection = db.collection("ag");
var cursor = collection.aggregate([{ $group : {_id: '$a'}}])
cursor.toArray(function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  db.close();
});
```

what results with:

```
TypeError: Object #<SkinClass> has no method 'toArray'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../aggregation.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I've found that with the native driver the below code works (using get and setting the batchSize):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection("ag");

  var cursor = collection.aggregate([{ $group : {_id: '$a'}}], {cursor:{batchSize:100}});
  cursor.get(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

yet it fails with mongoskin.

Is the retrieval of the whole aggregation result the only option for mongoskin (below) or is there something I am missing?

```
var cursor = collection.aggregate([{ $group : {_id: '$a'}}], function(err, result) {
```